# regexp: multiline, non-greedy match until optional string

Tags: regex, go, re2

Using Go's regexp, I'm trying to extract a predefined set of ordered key-value (multiline) pairs whose last element may be optional from a raw text, e.g.,

```
 Key1:
  SomeValue1
  MoreValue1
 Key2:
  SomeValue2
  MoreValue2
 OptionalKey3:
  SomeValue3
  MoreValue3
```

(here, I want to extract all the values as named groups)

If I use the default greedy pattern `(?s:Key1:\n(?P<Key1>.*)Key2:\n(?P<Key2>.*)(?:OptionalKey3:\n(?P<OptionalKey3>.*))?)`, it never sees OptionalKey3 and matches the rest of the text as Key2.

If I use the non-greedy pattern `(?s:Key1:\n(?P<Key1>.*)Key2:\n(?P<Key2>.*?)(?:OptionalKey3:\n(?P<OptionalKey3>.*))?)`, it doesn't even see SomeValue2 and stops immediately: https://regex101.com/r/QE2g3o/1

Is there a way to optionally match OptionalKey3 while also able to capture all the other ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```golang
(?s)\AKey1:\n(?P<Key1>.*)Key2:\n(?P<Key2>.*?)(?:OptionalKey3:\n(?P<OptionalKey3>.*))?\z
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/jY8a3a/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?s)                     set flags for this block (with . matching
                           \n) (case-sensitive) (with ^ and $
                           matching normally) (matching whitespace
                           and # normally)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \A                       the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Key1:                    'Key1:'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?P<Key1>                 group and capture to "Key1":
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character (0 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of "Key1"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Key2:                    'Key2:'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?P<Key2>                group and capture to "Key2":
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character (0 or more times (matching
                             the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of "Key2"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    OptionalKey3:            'OptionalKey3:'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?P<OptionalKey3>         group and capture to "OptionalKey3":
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*                       any character (0 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of "OptionalKey3"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \z                       the end of the string
```

Comment: Ah, the trick is to add `\z` at the end so that it forces the entire text to be matched. Thanks!